# Why is "linux" in Bionic and Focal affected by CVE-2022-0847?

Tags: kernel, security

According to [Ubuntu Security](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0847) page, the `linux` project in Bionic and Focal has a status of "Needed". I'm assuming this project refers to `linux-generic` in the APT repository, so `linux` should be 4.15 in Bionic and 5.4 in Focal. I also made a brief test on Ubuntu Focal with `linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic` (amd64) and failed to exploit. Thus I assume Bionic on 4.15 is also unaffected.

So why is it still shown as "Needed" for Bionic and Focal?

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: @ThomasWard There's the chance that "Needed" has a different meaning than my interpretation. I wonder if that's the case.

Comment: yeah clarification sometimes is useful, thankfully I know how to get in touch with the security team people ;)

Comment: @LorenzKeel FYI: The blockquote serves as "border" for the image. See [Do images need a border around them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138594)

Comment: @iBug sincerely thanks for the link. I thought it was a typo, now I understand it's intended. Of course, feel free to restore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you to the Ubuntu Security Team for providing clarity on this, which in turn gave me the information I needed to answer you.

In this case, "Needed" means that it's not patched yet in Bionic or Focal kernels.  According to Marc Deslauriers via #ubuntu-security on IRC:

> the flaw exists in bionic and focal, but it's not exploitable
> (yet)
>
> we will patch bionic and focal during the next round of kernel updates
> just in case someone discovers another way to exploit the flaw

So while Bionic and Focal are 'affected' by the CVE, this is not yet exploitable, and will be patched in the next round of kernel updates on Bionic and Focal, just in case someone finds another way to exploit the flaw in those kernels.